# Raptor flowchart command

Tags: c#, raptor

Can someone show me how to convert C# command `.StartsWith();`on RAPTOR flowchart command?

```
string unos = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
if (unos.StartsWith("KR"))
     kr++;
else if (unos.StartsWith("ZG"))
     zg++;`
```

Here is a sample.

Answer (score 0):

its one of the limiting things about raptor, that in order to compare letters you need to convert it to an ASCII value then make you comparison using the (to_ascii) function.

hope this helps
G/L